# how to keep track of accordion(in masterpage) open status after page navigation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i am using jquery accordion as a menu in asp.net Masterpage.

This is jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".header").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("display");
        $(this).next("div .menu_body").slideToggle(500);
    });
});
```

This is html.

```
  <div id="MasterPage_Menu" class="menu_list">
  <p class="header">Header-1</p>
    <div class="menu_body">
        <a href="page1.aspx">Link-1</a>
    </div>
  <p class="header">Header-2</p>
    <div class="menu_body">
        <a href="page2.aspx">Link-2</a>
    </div>
  <p class="header">Header-3</p>
    <div class="menu_body">
        <a href="page3.aspx">Link-3</a>
   </div>
  </div>
```

According the code above, when the header is clicked, the content (menu_body) will be slided toggle.
The menu_body is hide at default, when the user click on the header, the menu_body is visible.

**Example Problem:** eg: 2 menu_body is visible, when i click on href = "page1.aspx", the page will be navigated to page2.aspx but the accordion will return to be default which all the menu_body is hidden.

Since I am using this accordion in master page, i fail to store the value to keep track of the accordion menu_body status into the hiddenfield when the page is navigated away. The value in hiddenfield will be reset.

I am thinking to store this in session, but in client page, it doesn't allow us to store value into the session.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `id` attributes to your headers:

```
<p class="header" id="header-1">Header-1</p>
    <div class="menu_body">
        <a href="page1.aspx">Link-1</a>
    </div>
```

Then you can pull the `id` out in your handler and use [`jquery.cookie`](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js) to track the open panel in a cookie:

```
$(".header").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.hasClass('display'))
        $.cookie('open_panel', this.id);
    $this.toggleClass("display");
    $this.next("div .menu_body").slideToggle(500);
});
```

You'd need to play with the storage format for `open_panel` a bit if you want to have multiple panels open at one time but a simple CSV list would probably suffice; I'll leave that part as an exercise for the reader. You'd also want to check the cookie when the page loads and open the appropriate panels.

You could also keep track of the cookie's value on the server if you wanted to keep the setting around as part of the user's account preferences.

Comment: @mu is too short: how can i get the cookie value set in asp.net code behind?

Comment: @DEN: My asp.net is pretty weak but maybe [this from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx) will be helpful. You'll probably want to look at the `expires`, `path`, `domain`, and other options for `$.cookie` as well.

Comment: @mu is too short: i face some problem using cookie.For your information,the cookie i set will only refer to the page i click. For example, in page1.aspx, if i store the "abc" into $.cookie('open_panel'), i only can retrieve it on page1.aspx. that's mean when i am in page2.aspx, i am unable to retrieve the "abc" value which i set in page1.aspx :(

Comment: @DEN: Have a look at the `path` and `domain` options for `$.cookie`, they're documented in the `jquery.cookie.js` file I linked to. You'll probably want to call `$.cookie('open_panel', value, { path: somepath, domain: somedomain, ... })` or wrap something like that in a convenience function.

Comment: @mu is too short: wow..! the path and domain is quite confusing .. any document to read throught that?

Comment: @DEN: `path` and `domain` are just normal cookie properties, they're not specific to `$.cookie`. So check your favorite reference materials for clarification.