# How to keep Accordion Menu Open after Right Side content loads

Tags: javascript, php

I have used the W3 article "How to Create and Accordion Menu" to add an accordion menu to a webpage I am working on with a very long menu.

The CMS I a using is Joomla 3.62.

I have the page working but I find that when I select a menu option from the accordion menu, it closes the accordion.

Ideally I would like to keep the accordion section open once the right panel content loads, so another choice could be made in the same section of the accordion.

I am getting the hang of the PHP thing but my javascript is pretty weak, I was hoping someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

the javascript used is:

```
<script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
    this.classList.toggle("active");``
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}
</script>
```

The page in question is:

http://findlayfoods.com/category-display

Comment: The whole page reloads when you click one of the options. You could add another URL parameter to indicate which category was open. Alternatively, a cookie could store that information like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039343/how-to-keep-track-of-accordionin-masterpage-open-status-after-page-navigation?rq=1).

Comment: I have taken your advise to use the URL parameter method. It has take a bit to figure it out but I think I am well on my way to solving my problem. Thanks for your help!